# double click button using slidetoggle()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have run into a little problem. I am using a series of buttons that when pressed closes the previously visible  and then opens a  that is linked to that button.

That portion works great except when you double click a button when a different  is already open. It will then close the  linked to the button clicked. If you click on another button it will open the  linked to that button plus the previous  which you double clicked.

This bug can only be created when you double click a button that is not already active.

```
$(document).on('click', 'button', onButtonClick)

function onButtonClick() {
    target = $(this).attr('class')
    if ($('.active')[0]) {
        if(!$('.active').hasClass(target)) {
            $('.active').removeClass('active').slideToggle(function () {
                $('div.' + target).slideToggle().addClass('active')
            })
        }
    } else {
        $('div.' + target).slideToggle().addClass('active')
    }
}
```

Here is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/78TRb/

My question is there a way to only allow single clicks on the button to eliminate my bug or is there a better way?

Your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).on('click', 'button', onButtonClick)
var clicked = false;
function onButtonClick() {
    if(clicked)
    {
        return;
    }

    target = $(this).attr('class')
    if ($('.active')[0]) {
        if(!$('.active').hasClass(target)) {
            clicked = true;
            $('.active').removeClass('active').slideToggle(function () {
                $('div.' + target).slideToggle().addClass('active') 
                clicked = false;
            })
        }

    } else {
        $('div.' + target).slideToggle().addClass('active')
        clicked = false;
    }
}
```

Here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/78TRb/13/

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
$(document).on('click', 'button', onButtonClick)

function onButtonClick() {
    target = $(this).attr('class')
    if ($('.active')[0]) {
        if(!$('.active').hasClass(target)) {
            $('.active').removeClass('active').slideToggle(function () {
                $('div.' + target).slideToggle().addClass('active')
            })
        }
    } else {
        $('div.' + target).slideToggle().addClass('active')
    }
}
```

Here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/78TRb/11/